# How to parse a web page using Nokogiri in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse html.  For the website shown, I am trying to create an array of hashes where each hash will contain the pros, cons, and advice sections for a given review shown on the site.  I am having trouble doing this and was hoping for some advice here.  When I return a certain element, I don't get the right content shown on the site.  Any ideas?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

# Perform a google search
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Microsoft-Reviews-E1651.htm'))

reviews = []


current_review = Hash.new

doc.css('.employerReview').each do |item|
    pro = item.parent.css('p:nth-child(1) .notranslate').text
    con = item.parent.css('p:nth-child(2) .notranslate').text
    advice = item.parent.css('p:nth-child(3) .notranslate').text

    current_review = {'pro' => pro, 'con' => con, 'advice' => advice}

    reviews << current_review
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
reviews = []
doc.css('.employerReview').each do |item|
  pro, con, advice = item.css('.description .notranslate text()').map(&:to_s)
  reviews << {'pro' => pro, 'con' => con, 'advice' => advice}
end
```

It's also preferred with ruby to use symbol keys, so unless you need them to be strings, I'd do

```
reviews << { pro: pro, con: con, advice: advice }
```

Comment: When I have puts reviews[0]['pros'], it doesn't return the full text as seen on the site.  I think it's due to the css selector, which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: 1st its `'pro'` and not `'pros'`, 2nd it worked for me: `Very little bureaucracy for such a large organization. Generally tends toward moving fast with limited planning.`

Comment: I meant pro, that's what I have in my code.  And that's strange, that's not the text I see for the first pro entry on the page...

Comment: ah it just changed. Maybe refresh, because you could be checking against an old page